# Xml parsing, continuing a foreach loop in another method

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, loops, foreach

I have a XML file, organized in a way similar to this:

```
<People>
    <Person>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <SurName>Smith</SurName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Jack</Name>
        <SurName>Woodman</SurName>
    </Person>
    [...]
</People>
<Professions>
    <Person>
        <SurName>Smith</SurName>
        <Profession>Blacksmith</Profession>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <SurName>Woodman</SurName>
        <Profession>Lumberjack</Profession>
    </Person>
        [...]
    </Professions>
```

Ok, here we go.
I am parsing this using Xml.Linq and I've got sth like this code:

```
 foreach (XElement datatype in RepDoc.Element("People").Descendants("Persons"))
 {
     Name=datatype.Element("Name").Value;
     SurName=datatype.Element("SurName").Value;
 }
```

But, the question is if it is possible to open another foreach, inside another method, starting on the current `datatype` position without parsing from the beginning again.
As if the method inherit the XElement `datatype`, so I could start parsing from the same `<Person>`node.

It sounds stupid, but I can't put the original .xml because it is huge and has millions of information that would just confuse us more.

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, but for what purpose? I assume that you want to iterate through descendents of the `People` tag?

Comment: You could try casting the `Descendants()` result `ToList()` and using a `for` loop (with the indexes of the list). Then, the nested `for` loop would start at `index+1`. Hope I understand your question correctly. Could you please provide some details?

Comment: I think to do this you'd have to pass a list to the new method of which elements that are 'left'. This sounds like a very odd move though; it would help if you specified what would be done in the other foreach.

Comment: @DavidS. I editted the question with a last paragraph trying to explain what would be done. The .xml is huge, so Listing is out of question. But Thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I believe you're looking for `yield`. This would often be used like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    foreach (XElement datatype in RepDoc.Element("People").Descendants("Persons"))
    {
        var p = new Person
        {
            Name = datatype.Element("Name").Value,
            SurName = datatype.Element("SurName").Value
        };

        yield return p;
    }
}
```

and then you could use that method like this:

```
foreach (Person p in MyClass.GetPeople())
```

The benefit here is that you only read as much of the XML file as is necessary because if you break out of the outer-loop, everything stops.

Comment: So, this foreach  would start parsing exactly where datatype stopped?

Comment: @ViniciusSilveira, this would parse one `Persons` at a time.